# Mongoose - Consultas con OR y AND

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Estoy tratando de hacer una query en mongoose y no se me ocurre muy bien como armarla.
En SQL sería algo asi:

```
SELECT * FROM MATERIAS 
WHERE
     activo = true AND 
     nivel = $nivel_id AND
    (alldisc = true OR disciplina = $disciplina_id)
```

siendo `$nivel_id` y `$disciplina_id` variables.

Esto mismo lo estoy escribiendo en nodejs y mongoose y no se me ocurre bien como hacerlo.

Lo que he hecho hasta ahora es:

```
function getMateriasFilter(req, res) {
    var query = Materia.find({'active': true});

    if (req.query.nivel)        query.where('nivel', req.query.nivel);
    if (req.query.disciplina)   query.where('disciplina', req.query.disciplina).or('alldisc', true);

    query
        .populate('nivel')
        .populate('periodo')
        .populate('disciplina')
        .exec(function(err, result) {
            if (err) res.send(err);
            res.json(result); 
        });
}
```

La linea con el if de disciplina me complica.
Esa condición sería que si existe el filtro de disciplina, me tiene que traer el que coincida con la disciplina o los que tengan el campo alldisc en true.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Ezequien, bienvenido. Dices que eso mismo estás intentando en `NodeJS` y en `Mangoose`... puedes pegar lo que has intentado para que sobre eso podamos ayudarte?

Comment: Hola @lois6b, He agregado el código que tengo hecho. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo **siempre trabajar en capas**, delegar funcionalidades específicas a cada una para que se tenga una sola responsabilidad. Recuerda que una aplicación altamente acoplada/cohesiva, significa una muy baja probabilidad de que pueda escalar y mantenerse en un futuro.

La siguiente clase actúa como *repositorio* para una colección. Su función es simplemente consultar a la base de datos.

> **Consejo:** de preferencia tiende a usar [`Promesas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) en lugar de callbacks ya que provee una sintaxis limpia en procesos complejos (evitando los [*callback hell*](http://callbackhell.com/)) y además, te verás beneficiado si decides usar la **recientemente aprobada especificación** [`async/await`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions) **que saldrá en ES2017**.

```
class MateriaRepository {
  filter (nivel disciplina) {
    let where = { active: true };

    if (nivel) {
      where.nivel = nivel;
    }

    if (disciplina) {
      where.$or = [
        {
          alldisc: true
        },
        {
          disciplina
        }
      ]
    }

    return (
      Materia
        .find(where)
        .populate('nivel')
        .populate('periodo')
        .populate('disciplina')
        .exec()
    );
  }
}
```

De esta manera puedes usar dichos métodos en cualquier lugar.

```
function getMateriasFilter (req, res) {
  let repository = new MateriaRepository();
  let { nivel, disciplina } = req.query;

  repository
    .filter(nivel, disciplina)
    .then((materias) => (
      res.jsonp(materias)
    ));
}
```

---

La anterior consulta se explica de la siguiente manera:

1. Por defecto, el *where* solo especifica que se seleccionen solo las materias activas (`active: true`).
2. Si el parámetro `nivel` está disponible, añade una entrada al *where* para que se seleccione solo las materias activas y tengan el nivel especificado.
3. Si el parámetro disciplina está disponible, se añade una entrada de tipo [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) al *where* para seleccionar las materias *activas*, *de cierto nivel* y *de cierta disciplina* o *si la materia tiene* `alldisc: true`.